# ReSharper "Cannot resolve symbol" between projects in brand-new dnx solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, resharper, dnx, dnx50

**My Setup:**

- VisualStudio 2015 Update1
- ReSharper Ultimate 9.2
- dnvm version 1.0.0-rc1-update2 clr x86

**What I have done so far:**

I 've created a brand-new solution with 2 projects:

1. Visual C#/Web -> "Class Library (Package)
2. Visual C#/Web -> "Console Application (Package)

and added a reference of the class library to the console application.

The project.json of the class library looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "DnxExampleClassLibrary Class Library",
  "authors": [ "John Doe" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "frameworks": {
    "net451": { },
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The project.json of the console application looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "DnxExampleConsoleApp Console Application",
  "authors": [ "John Doe" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "DnxExampleClassLibrary": "1.0.0-*"
  },

  "commands": {
    "DnxExampleConsoleApp": "DnxExampleConsoleApp"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, when I try to create an instance of Class1 (that is in the class library project) inside my `Main` function, ReSharper tells me, that it cannot resolve the symbol.

[image]

The project compiles and when I suspend ReSharper, everything looks good.
I also tried to "ReSharper/Options -> Environment/General -> Clear Caches" but that didn't solve the problem either.

What do I do wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing [ReSharper 10.1 EAP build](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+10.1+EAP), the following issues have been fixed there: [one](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-447817), [two](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-453649), [three](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-452847). So it should support the latest dnx version (ReSharper 9.2 can't support "1.0.0-rc1-update2" since R# 9.2 build was released about 9 months ago).

Comment: This looks like it could solve my problems. I don't have a license for Version10 yet, but because the bug list describes exactly the issues I have, I mark this answer as the accepted one.